# Adjusting tikz dotted line on page

Tags: tikz-pgf, columns

I am writing a multi-page CV using a modified template from [howtotex.com](http://www.howtotex.com/templates/creating-a-designers-cv-in-latex/). However, I get a short line of dots at the top left of the second page. How can I get rid of this? I assume that I would have to edit the `tikz` part of the code, but I'm note sure how to do this.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth} \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line 
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0] (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame 
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

% horizontal rule between frames (using TikZ)
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{%
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=-#1] 
    (0,0) -- (0pt,#3);}%
\hfill\mbox{}}
\insertvrule{flow}{1}{flow}{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} Personal Profile}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}

\newcommand{\bluebullet}{\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$\color{Black}\hspace{1em}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}\small
    My Name \\
    \hfill \\
    Address 1 \\
    Address 2 \\
    Address 3 \\
    Address 4 \\
    \hfill \\
    Phone Number \\
\end{flushright}
\framebreak

% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{Black} My Name} \\

\normalsize\normalfont

\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

\CVSection{Education}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\CVSection{Work Experience}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

%Awards
\CVSection{Awards}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\CVSection{Computer software}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    \bluebullet Python & Excellent \\
    \bluebullet C++ & Good \\
\end{tabular}
\Sep 

\CVSection{Other stuff}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\clearpage
\framebreak
\framebreak

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate that be changing the definition of `\ffvrule`:

```
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth} \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line 
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0] (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame 
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

% horizontal rule between frames (using TikZ)
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{}% <---- Eliminated this code.
\insertvrule{flow}{1}{flow}{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} Personal Profile}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}

\newcommand{\bluebullet}{\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$\color{Black}\hspace{1em}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}\small
    My Name \\
    \hfill \\
    Address 1 \\
    Address 2 \\
    Address 3 \\
    Address 4 \\
    \hfill \\
    Phone Number \\
\end{flushright}
\framebreak

% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{Black} My Name} \\

\normalsize\normalfont

\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

\CVSection{Education}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\CVSection{Work Experience}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

%Awards
\CVSection{Awards}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\CVSection{Computer software}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    \bluebullet Python & Excellent \\
    \bluebullet C++ & Good \\
\end{tabular}
\Sep 

\CVSection{Other stuff}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

\clearpage
\framebreak
\framebreak

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

\end{document}
```